# Rails mailer image attachment from data uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, gmail, email-attachments

I have saved a signature which is in the form of a image data uri, png and stored in my database as a string.

When sending an email, I want to attach it inline but the image keeps showing up as not working in Gmail. Here is my code:

Mailer:

```
attachments.inline['signature'] = {
  content: @project_addition.signature.split(',')[1],
  mime_type: 'image/png',
  encoding: 'base64'
}
```

View:

```
<%= image_tag attachments.inline['signature'].url, width: '25%' %>
```

First few chars of the string:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABowAAAC4CA....
```

Comment: What error do you get from gmail

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII no error, just no image showing up (only a box with a question mark in the middle, which is gmail saying it cannot understand attachment)

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have the image data uri, another solution is put below method in your helper

app/helpers/email_helper.rb

```
  def email_data_uri(image, **options)
    code = File.open("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/#{image}", 'r').read
    data = Base64.strict_encode64(code)
    type = image.split('.')[-1]
    name = image.split('/')[-1]
    attachments.inline[name] = {
      content: Base64.decode64(data),
      mime_type: "image/#{type}"
    }
    image_tag attachments.inline[name].url, **options
  end
```

app/view/campaign_mailer

```
= email_data_uri 'email/livechat-logo.png', style: 'width: 34px'
```

adding the style options

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Base64.decode64` to decode the base64 encoded content and not specifiy encoding

```
attachments.inline['signature'] = {
  content: Base64.decode64(@project_addition.signature.split(',')[1]),
  mime_type: 'image/png'
}
```